# Can i write a request code in my vscode extension in development?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am developing a vscode extension and want to send a request to get open api's data,but i dont't know if vscode extension support 'send request in extension'(i had searched document and no result).
If anyone understands the problem,please tell me what to do.

Comment: i want to use a get request in my code,but i don't know  which api i should call in vscode extension.

Comment: thank you for answer.vscode extension is running in node environment,so it seems that i cant't use JavaScript/TypeScript API  in developing.i try the native https API in node and success.